# Pages Show StaticFile Handler 404.0 Error in WordPress on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, iis-7.5

I'm moving a WordPress site to a server that runs WordPress on IIS 7.5. Barf. The server is already hosting two other sites without any problems.

The new site that I migrated shows the homepage, images, and all the wp-admin pages perfectly.

When I try to view a "page" such as `/about`, I get a 404. IIS seems to try and handle the request with a StaticFileHandler.  In `wp-admin` I can see the page and all the content looks correct.

How can I get this page to render correctly?

*The admin page:*

[image]

*After clicking 'view page':*

[image]

Comment: Did you set up the permalinks properly? If so, you may need to flush them and try again by changing to a different style of permalinks and back.

Comment: They were setup properly, but changing them to something else and back worked! Thanks so much - post it as a real answer & I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush your permalinks.

Change the permalinks to something other than what they're set at, then change them back, should flush the rewrite rules and work correctly.

Comment: Even better, you don't even need to change your setting and then change back.  Simply clicking "Save Changes" on the Custom Permalinks page will perform a flush.